# Proof titles with ntheorem

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I am using the `ntheorem` package.  I have a theorem in a document where the proof appears somewhat later.  When I start the proof, I'd like to indicate what exactly I am proving.  Currently the code I am using looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}

\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[Proof of something]
  Proof here.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

This results in output like:

> **Proof (Proof of something)** Proof here.

I would like it to instead just look like

> **Proof of something.**  Proof here.

Is it possible to do this?  This will happen several times in the document, so I'd rather not create a custom environment for each instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide your own theorem style.

Try:

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

With the definition above you will get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Proof here.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}[Proof of something]
  Proof here.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you add a QED symbol to the end of the proof?