# QED symbol at end of special proof environment?

Tags: theorems, ntheorem, proof-package

This is a follow up question to: [Proof titles with ntheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106072/proof-titles-with-ntheorem/106074#comment947930_106074)

But since the original answer-er has not been seen for a month, I'd like to ask a wider community of people.

How do you add a QED symbol to the end of the specially defined proof environment:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to declare the `\qedsymbol` *before* you declare the `proof` environment. Sole condition for working: no blank line before `\end{proof}`.

This being said, I don't see why you declare a personal `NoNumberPlain` theorem style which is the exact copy of the already defined `nonumberplain`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
```

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

```
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep##1{ }##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{MyNonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{. ---}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{Gainsboro}\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{th-a}
This theorem is awesome!
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Because I can change the position of qed mark correctly! Blahblah Blahblah Blahblah. 
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of \cref{th-a}]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The idea is that when you title the proof, say begin{proof}[Proof of Thm 1], it should look like "Proof of Theorem 1" and not "Proof (Proof of Theorem 1"), which is what your code would generate. The code in the question allows this naming of proofs. Can you provide a way to both name proofs, as above, and have the QED symbol?

Comment: Pressed enter too early; comment edited above

Comment: I see. I've already done the same quite some years ago. Actually, I simplified you code: you just have to type the complement. I also loaded `cleverref` for a smarter typing of cross-references.